# IDT 92HD93 driver for Windows 10

Tags: audio, drivers, windows-10, sound-card, microphone

I have a 2-year old Dell Latitude E6330 with an IDT 92HD93 sound card. Unfortunately there don't seem to be any Windows 10 drivers for that card (I've looked almost everywhere), and the Windows 8.1 drivers don't work properly (microphone doesn't record sometimes, or sound comes out of the wrong speakers, among other things).

This is what I found on [IDT's website](http://www.idt.com/products/audio-products):

> Notice: IDT’s AC97, HD Audio and Consumer audio codecs are now being sold and supported by Tempo Semiconductor, Inc. For sales and support information, please visit Tempo Semiconductor at www.temposemi.com.

So basically it looks like my audio card is no longer supported (as I couldn't find anything on Tempo Semiconductor's website either).

Now, if it was just a regular single microphone, I wouldn't be so bothered by all that. Unfortunately the microphone that's in my laptop is actually a microphone array, which doesn't seem to be properly supported by the standard Microsoft drivers.

Is there still a way to unlock the full potential of my sound card? (namely the microphone array)

To reiterate: I tried the Windows 8.1 drivers I found on Dell's website, but they didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Your drivers can be downloaded from Dell support page. I cannot post URL here, try to search it.
You can get Your audio driver, when it will be released. You may ask Dell support for date. Now I cant find an audio driver for Windows 10. You may try to use Windows 8.1 driver. It may work.

Comment: As I said in the question, I tried the Windows 8.1 drivers, but they don't work correctly.
It's also unlikely that new drivers will be released, as the last one is from more than a year ago, and IDT has since stopped support for their audio products.